# Bugged question (possibly rounding issue)

Tags: bug, status-deferred

[This Question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/230870/generate-the-shortest-regex-to-match-these-but-not-those) was asked 2 months ago but was closed *3 months* ago, I'm assuming this is a bug.

> @Bubbler said that it may be a rounding issue, as "the exact date and time when each event occurred ... are in correct order."

Screenshot:

[image: Confusing Image]

Comment: This is bug that's happened before, I'll try to find a report

Comment: Okay, thanks, I added the link, refresh

Comment: Pretty sure it's a rounding issue in one way or another. If you hover your mouse over the text "x months ago", you can see the exact date and time when each event occurred, and they are in correct order.

Comment: [EDITED COMMENT] I edited the question to include your comment, @Bubbler, but what will happen with the bug? Also, can someone move this to chat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correction: this is actually [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred), per JNat's answer to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/347355/355458) [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) report on MSE. Unfortunately, not much more information about this was given in his answer, but, aside from the first sentence below, this answer is (mostly) still correct.

---

This is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). The Asked/Active times aren't exact, and have a bit of a weird calculation time. I believe that, because only 2 full months have passed, it counts as 2 months ago. Wait until the 1st of October and it'll say "3 months ago".

It wouldn't surprise me if you can figure out this behaviour from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11/7742131), asked by [Jeff Atwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood), the founder of Stack Overflow. Note that that question was the *eleventh* post on Stack Overflow,

As mentioned by [Bubbler](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/78410/bubbler) in the [comments](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23877/broken-question#comment75185_23877), if you hover your mouse over the "2 months ago", it'll give the exact timestamp:

[image: screenshot of date/time on hover]

As for why the close date shows "3 months ago", but the Asked/Active shows "2 months ago", who knows? The close votes system has been regularly updated since the founding of SO, but I think the Asked/Answered has been the same since at least [2014](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/244461/355458), so probably uses some outdated / different method.